# Installing multiple apps inside a master app in android and showing only master app

Tags: android

This is the first question I am asking on stack overflow so go easy on me.

I have been assigned the task of building a large android app and I have thought of the following architecture owing to the large size of the app:

There will be a master app that user will download from the play store and this app will have symbols of multiple apps which user will have to download when she will use it for the first time. And only those sub-apps will run which user will use at the particular instant.

The problem is that I don't want to show the sub-apps in the user phone i.e. I want to hide all those small apps and want to show only the master app.

Is it possible? I am not able to find anything on Google.

Comment: "Is it possible?" -- what **exactly** is "it"?

Comment: " it ": hiding all smaller apps in the user's phone and showing only the master app at the same time smaller apps are available within the master app.

Comment: Note that Google doesn't like apps which install other apps (it's against the play store terms) so you will need to be aware of that if you distribute your "master" app through Google Play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main places where apps show up: the home screen (particularly its launcher), and the Settings app.

You cannot hide these "smaller apps" from the user with respect to the Settings app.

However, you do not necessarily have to have an activity in those "smaller apps" that has the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>`. In that case, the home screen's launcher will not show any icons for those "smaller apps".

Your "master app" would need to know how to start some activity associated with each "smaller app", such as via a custom category (instead of `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` use `com.kia.intent.category.SMALL_APP_LAUNCHER` or something).

Comment: Need one more suggestion, will using plugins solve this? Meaning each smaller apps can be installed as plugin in the main app.

Comment: @KIA: What I described *is* a plugin. It's not like Android has something that is specifically described as a plugin system.

Comment: so how MPL/Hagoo use this scenario here one master app have multiple games app which launched form master app and all small have no any info in setting app or any where how they work?

Comment: @HiteshKushwah: If you are referring to [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yy.hiyo), presumably those games are simply features of the main app. Or, they could be some form of content rendered by the app, much like how this Web page is content rendered by a Web browser app.